# Does 32-bit mips cmpxchg(cas) support 8 Bytes?

Tags: mips, compare-and-swap, double-compare-and-swap

everyone. I am writing a program in 32-bit mips using double words to avoid ABA problem. But it seems that 32-bit mips does not support 8 Bytes in Linux kernel source code. If so, is there anybody knowing 8 Bytes extension?  Are there other ways to avoid ABA problem?